# Limit the bandwidth while downloading

Tags: java, android, download, httpurlconnection

I have an app that can use internet connection to downloading data. I'm using `HttpURLConnection` to do that.

**Problem:** My app drains the internet bandwidth, so users will browsing slowly on their Browser. I want to make them optionally to set the bandwidth limit by itself, not like [this site](http://www.digit.in/mobile-phones/how-to-set-internet-data-limit-on-android-phones-and-tablets-20050.html). I have knew about it.

**Question:** How to set the bandwidth limit while downloading? For example: 500 KB/s (KiloBytes per second).

Here's my method to download a file:

```
// These are the status codes.
public static final int DOWNLOADING = 0;
public static final int PAUSED = 1;
public static final int COMPLETE = 2;
public static final int CANCELLED = 3;
public static final int ERROR = 4;

private long downloaded;
private int status;

private void downloadFile(String requestUrl) throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = null;
    RandomAccessFile output = null;
    status = DOWNLOADING;
    downloaded = 0;
    URL url = new URL(requestUrl);

    try {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        output = new RandomAccessFile(my_directory, "rw");

        // Open connection to URL.
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.connect();

        // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            status = ERROR;
        }

        stream = connection.getInputStream();
        while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

            // Read from server into buffer.
            int read = stream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1)
                break;

            // Write buffer to file.
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            downloaded += read;
        }
        status == COMPLETE;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        status = ERROR;
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        // Close connection to server.
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had a `Socket` you could just set the receive buffer size to the desired bandwidth-delay product, but, as you don't, you will just have to sleep between receive calls. Experiment or some feedback-based arithmetic will yield the appropriate sleep intervals.

Answer (score -1):

You can have preference like download in Mobile data/Wifi/ Roaming in your settings activity. You can get the connection type with this class.

> /**  * Check device's network connectivity and speed   * @author Max
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/801646/max  *  */ public class
>   Connectivity {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Get the network info
>  * @param context
>  * @return
>  */
> public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
>     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>     return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Check if there is any connectivity
>  * @param context
>  * @return
>  */
> public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
>     NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>     return (info != null && info.isConnected());
> }
>
> /**
>  * Check if there is any connectivity to a Wifi network
>  * @param context
>  * @param type
>  * @return
>  */
> public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
>     NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>     return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Check if there is any connectivity to a mobile network
>  * @param context
>  * @param type
>  * @return
>  */
> public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
>     NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>     return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Check if there is fast connectivity
>  * @param context
>  * @return
>  */
> public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
>     NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>     return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
> }
>
> /**
>  * Check if the connection is fast
>  * @param type
>  * @param subType
>  * @return
>  */
> public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
>     if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
>         return true;
>     }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
>         switch(subType){
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
>             return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
>             return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
>             return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
>             return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
>             return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
>             return false; // ~ 100 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
>             return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
>             return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
>             return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
>             return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
>         /*
>          * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
>          * to appropriate level to use these
>          */
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
>             return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
>             return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
>             return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
>             return false; // ~25 kbps 
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
>             return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
>         // Unknown
>         case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
>         default:
>             return false;
>         }
>     }else{
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: sorry, it doesn't give the exact limit.

Comment: This doesn't *set* a limit at all, just provides various pieces of information.