# How can I limit the Internet connection via wifi in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I need my Android device working with 10 Kbytes of uploaded data when it's connect to wifi connection. I need just to upload 10 Kbps no matter if the connection provides more than 10. I don't know if wifi API provides some code to do this, but I need to develop an app that makes it. So how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? (just curious)

Comment: Do you want your app to be limited to 10KBytes of upload or ALL apps on the phone?

Comment: All the apps need to be limited to 10 KBytes

Comment: I know to create Services running in background. But I don't know if I can limit the wifi connection

Comment: I have asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27317857/3922207