# Bandwidth limit for apps in Android

Tags: android, bandwidth

In Android, is there any limitation on bandwidth usage for an app/process/thread/connection? How does it manage apps concurrently using internet, that prevents a single app of sucking up the bandwidth?

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27317857/3922207

Comment: @AnggrayudiH No, that's a different situation, that guy wants to limit the bandwidth, but I want to know is there any limitation applied by Android or not.